# Want to pick image files from a specific folder but have all the files of gallery instead

Tags: android, android-intent, image-gallery, android-gallery

Want to pick image files from a specific folder  vaibhav but have all the files of gallery instead.

**Code**

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Vaibhav/");
                Log.e("Dir path",dir.toString());
                dir.exists();
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(dir.toString());
                Intent browseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(uri.toString()));

                browseIntent.setType("image/jpg");

                startActivityForResult(browseIntent, BROWSE_REQUEST);
```

Comment: what is the output of this Log.e("Dir path",dir.toString());?

Comment: The path which i want

Comment: show the path here..

Comment: something like sdcard/0/pictures/vaibhav

Comment: do Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    + "/you_folder_name/");

Comment: done the same thing but not helped.

Comment: and yes one more thing if i am not setting up the type than i do get the error msg "no activity found to handle intent."

Comment: @AdesrTf what do you do in `onActivityResult` after you pick a image?

Comment: Compress by bitmap..

Comment: If anyone comes up with any idea please let me know. this is really important for me..

Answer (score 1):

Following Code Just Works Fine:

```
public void openFolder()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    + "/Vaibhav/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say but it shows all the files in gallery.

Comment: Anjali If you come up with any idea please let me know. this is really important for me..

Comment: you can create your own file explorer

Comment: How to fetch all images from particular folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Use 
  browseIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*.*");//Loads all image files
Instead of
  browseIntent.setType("image/jpg");